# Mysql-php Using static or non static connection?

Tags: php, oop, mysqli

I am new to this subject.I am just trying to connect my db and fetch data. When working with static connection it is working but working with nonstatic not.As I said I don't know much about Php, probably missing something easy.
Error when trying to get nonstatic The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred.
My code

```
> <?php


class DB_Connect extends mysqli{

  //  protected static $connection;//working
       protected  $connection;   / not working


    function __construct() {

    }


    function __destruct() {


    }
    public function connect() {  
        if(!isset($this->$connection)) {

            $config = parse_ini_file('./configOop.ini'); 
            $this->$connection = new mysqli($config['dbhost'],$config['username'],$config['password'],$config['dbname']);

        }
        else{}
         return $this->$connection;
         /*
        // using this part for static connection object, working
        if(!isset(self::$connection)) {

            $config = parse_ini_file('./configOop.ini'); 
            self::$connection = new mysqli($config['dbhost'],$config['username'],$config['password'],$config['dbname']);

        }
        else{}


        return self::$connection;
        */
    }


    // Closing database connection
    public function close() {
      //  mysql_close();
    }

} 
?>
```

//

```
    <?php  include 'db_connectOop.php'; ?>
<?php
 // error_reporting(0);
  $db=new DB_Connect();
   $dbConn=$db->connect();



   if($result =$dbConn->query("Select * from cities")or die($dbConn->error)){

   if($count=$result->num_rows){

      while($row = $result->fetch_object())
      {
       echo $row->idcities;
      }
   }
 }

?>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A tiny mistake: `$this->$connection` should be `$this->connection`.

PHP doesn't need the second `$`, since it already knows (because of the `->`) that you are referring to a property. If you would add that `$` like you did, you are basically getting the value of the local variable `$connection`, and using that value as the property name.

Comment: ov ty :). What to do when connecting server? Should I use static, nonstatic, singleton , dependency injection.What do you suggest. I will be getting information to android application from remote database.

Comment: Just my opinion: Dependency injection is by far the best options of the ones you listed. Static and singleton are basically encapsulated globals.